# Realm Swift select all values which match one field in one-to-many relationship entity

Tags: swift, swift3, realm, nspredicate

I have two entities in realm Product and ProductType. Product has one to many relation with Product Type.

**Product entity one to many**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Product: Object{
    dynamic var productName = ""
    let productTypeList = List<ProductType>() 
}
```

**ProductType entity**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class ProductType: Object{   
  dynamic var typeName: String = ""
  dynamic var typeLogoUrl: String = ""
}
```

My goal is select all products, which contains ProductType typeName, for example "Electronics". I can do it easily, if there were one to one relationship like this

**Product entity one to one**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Product:Object{
    dynamic var productName = ""
    dynamic var productType : ProductType? 
}
```

**Query example**

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let productTypeName = "Electronics"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "productType.typeName == %@", productTypeName)
let rmProducts = realm.objects(Product.self).filter(predicate)
```

Any ideas how to make query with one to many version of Product class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery and check that the count of the productTypes in the list matching the name is bigger than 0.

`let rmProducts = realm.objects(Product.self).filter("SUBQUERY(productTypeList, $type, $type.typeName == %@).@count>0",productTypeName)`

I have run the query on the following test set and got the expected results:

```
class Product:Object{
    dynamic var productName = ""
    var productTypeList = List<ProductType>()
}

class ProductType  : Object{
    dynamic var typeName: String = ""
    dynamic var typeLogoUrl: String = ""
}

let types = [ProductType(value: ["typeName":"Electronics","typeLogoUrl":"url"]),ProductType(value: ["typeName":"a","typeLogoUrl":"url"]),ProductType(value: ["typeName":"Electronics","typeLogoUrl":"a"]),ProductType(value: ["typeName":"b","typeLogoUrl":"url"])]

let prod1 = Product()
prod1.productName = "a"
prod1.productTypeList = List([types[0],types[1]])
let prod2 = Product()
prod2.productName = "b"
prod2.productTypeList = List([types[3],types[1]])
let prod3 = Product()
prod3.productName = "c"
prod3.productTypeList = List([types[2],types[1]])
var prod4 = Product()
prod4.productName = "d"
prod4.productTypeList = List([types[1]])

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(types)
    realm.add([prod1,prod2,prod3,prod4])
}

let productTypeName = "Electronics"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "productType.typeName == %@", productTypeName)
let rmProducts = realm.objects(Product.self).filter("SUBQUERY(productTypeList, $type, $type.typeName == %@).@count>0",productTypeName)
print(rmProducts) //rmProducts contains prod1 and prod3 as expected
```

Answer (score 3):

For a simple query like this, you want the `ANY` modifier:

```
realm.objects(Product.self).filter("ANY productTypeList.typeName == %@", productTypeName)
```

A `SUBQUERY`, as suggested in another answer, is only necessary if you need more than one criteria on each sub-object to match. For instance, if you wanted to find `Products` that have items of a given type whose URLs start with `https://` you would use a `SUBQUERY`:

```
realm.objects(Product.self).filter("SUBQUERY(productTypeList, $type, $type.typeName == %@ AND $type.typeLogoUrl BEGINSWITH 'https://').@count > 0", productTypeName)
```